# Sass mistakenly converts rgba function to hex

Tags: sass, nuxt.js

I have the following SASS code in a SASS file which is imported to my Vue component in Nuxt 3:

```
.page {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
```

I convert this to CSS using `nuxt generate` (with 3.0.0-rc.8), I get the following output:

```css
.page {
  background-color: #000000de;
}
```

This is wrong, because there is no opacity anymore. The output should be:

```css
.page {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
```

**What causes this problem?**

Side note: I could use `opacity` property instead of `rgba`, but it cannot always replace `rgba`, for example if I have `box-shadow: 0 -0.1rem 0.4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;`

Comment: The hex code is actually equal to the rgba one. You have 3x`00` and then `de` which is matching 0,87.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that hex code can have an alpha value. But something is still wrong because the element is not transparent (it is if I replace the generated hex code with the rgba function call in the generated CSS)

Comment: use string interpolation if you want the native functon instead of the sass function: `background-color: #{'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)'};`

Answer (score 0):

Both the RGBA and hex values are the same.
Hex using 6 digits for regular RBG channels, the 2 last ones (if provided) are used for the alpha channel.

You can find an online converter here: https://rgbacolorpicker.com/rgba-to-hex

Otherwise, you can also try those directly into the browser.

I've used an alpha of `0.15` because `0.87` is quite hard to see (`1` being totally opaque as a reminder), but it is totally equal for all the values as you can expect.

For that example, pick the sidebar on the right and apply both properties, toggle them back and forth and you'll notice no difference as expected.

[image]

Moreover, the devtools can provide you the convertion directly, click on the color icon (just on the right side of `background-color` and before the actual value), then click on the arrows on the bottom right of the popup.

[image]

So, if something is not working, it may come from somewhere else but both are totally equal from a CSS point of view.